# Fault tolerant USB HID communication

Tags: c++, winapi, usb, hid, fault-tolerance

Is there a way to send fault tolerant USB communication over HID where the standard Windows driver doesn't throw BROKEN_PIPE when an error is detected?

In my experience, the generic HID driver in Windows is prone to surrender on the first sign of issues with HID bulk transfers. It sets the BROKEN_PIPE flag. Then all future communication is impossible unless the driver is reloaded with administrative privileges. I think this is also true for interrupt transfers.

The issue is not adding checksums and packet counters to the protocol. The issue is figuring out how to convince the Windows driver to never surrender, to do its utmost to deliver the packets (or drop them) when faced with adverse conditions.

Avoiding administrative privileges, and avoiding writing a special driver is paramount.

Can we pack the data in control transfers? Are these also prone to causing broken pipes? What is the UDP equivalent for USB?

I've tried to send bulk transfers over HID but these cause BROKEN_PIPE. I've also tried sending interrupt transfers but these also seem to cause BROKEN_PIPE. I would expect the existence of a UDP-like mode where the HID driver drops packets that are obviously bad but where the connection stays open. Where communication is best-effort and any data that gets through is allowed through without giving up.

Comment: If you use the in-box driver, you get its behavior.  Writing a new driver is how you get total control over the behavior.

Comment: Could this possibly be due to sending messages that exceed PIPE_BUF bytes? And be mitigated by simply sending individual packets that never exceed the limit?

Comment: @JesperJuhl unfortunately not. The packets are less than 60 bytes. Most are much smaller, such as 10-20 bytes.

Comment: @BenVoigt I would really really like to avoid writing a driver. Is there a battle-tested signed driver that I can use instead?

Comment: Yes, it's called WinUSB.  It comes with Windows and you can make it load automatically by just adding some MS OS 2.0 descriptors to your device.  There are several user-space libaries that support it, including libusb and libusbp.

Comment: @DavidGrayson nice! I will give that a try :)

Comment: I should probably mention that I've had experiences where some part of a Windows PC gives up on communicating with a USB device due to electrical noise or something on the USB port.  I don't think it's WinUSB's fault though, it's probably Windows or the lower-level drivers/hardware.  Just wanted to let you know that using WinUSB isn't some magic bullet that will solve everything, but it is pretty reliable and able to handle things like a request failing due to buggy firmware.